# Ball Collision sticking to a static ball

Tags: c#, collision-detection

I have this setup where balls are colliding, when all have a velocity it works great, but now I'm trying to make them collide with an static one, so I've made a staticBall where the velocity is always 0 and can't be set.

But when a collision occurs, the ball (not static) sticks to the static one. but I don't know why.

What am I doing wrong? here is the code used for making them bounce.
Any other remarks to the code is welcome ;)

BallBase:

```
public abstract class BallBase {
    protected Vector _vel;

    public virtual Vector Vel {
        get { return _vel; }
        set { _vel = value; }
    }

    public Point Pos { get; set; }

    public double Rad { get; set; }

    public abstract void Tick(double deltaTime, double width, double height);
    public abstract Shape Paint();

}
```

Ball:

```
public class Ball : BallBase {
    public Ball(Point pos, double rad, Vector vel) {
        Pos = pos;
        Rad = rad;
        _vel = vel;
    }

    public override Vector Vel {
        get { return _vel; }
        set { _vel = value; }
    }

    public override Shape Paint() {
        return new Ellipse {
            Fill = Brushes.DarkBlue,
            Width = Rad*2,
            Height = Rad*2,
            Margin = new Thickness(Pos.X - Rad, Pos.Y - Rad, 0, 0)
        };
    }

    public override void Tick(double deltaTime, double width, double height) {
        Pos = new Point(Pos.X + Vel.X*deltaTime/1000, Pos.Y + Vel.Y*deltaTime/1000);

        if ((Pos.X + Rad) > width && Vel.X > 0) Vel = new Vector(Vel.X*-1, Vel.Y);
        if ((Pos.Y + Rad) > height && Vel.Y > 0) Vel = new Vector(Vel.X, Vel.Y*-1);
        if ((Pos.X - Rad) < 0 && Vel.X < 0) Vel = new Vector(Vel.X*-1, Vel.Y);
        if ((Pos.Y - Rad) < 0 && Vel.Y < 0) Vel = new Vector(Vel.X, Vel.Y*-1);
    }
}
```

StaticBall:

```
public class StaticBall : BallBase {
    public StaticBall(Point pos, double rad) {
        Pos = pos;
        Rad = rad;
        _vel = new Vector(0, 0);
    }

    public override Vector Vel {
        get { return _vel; }
        set { }
    }


    public override Shape Paint() {
        return new Ellipse {
            Fill = Brushes.Gray,
            Width = Rad*2,
            Height = Rad*2,
            Margin = new Thickness(Pos.X - Rad, Pos.Y - Rad, 0, 0)
        };
    }

    public override void Tick(double deltaTime, double width, double height) {}
}
```

Collision Handeling:

```
private void HandleCollisions() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _ball.Count; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < _ball.Count; ++j) //let op  j=i+1
        {
            // calculate distance between centers of balls
            Vector diff = _ball[i].Pos - _ball[j].Pos;
            double distance = diff.Length;
            // calculate sum of Radius
            double sumRadii = _ball[i].Rad + _ball[j].Rad;
            // check collision if dist<sum of diameters 
            if (distance < sumRadii)
                Bounce(i, j);
        }
    }
}

private void Bounce(int ball1, int ball2) {
    // vector that connects between both balls
    Vector centerNorm = (_ball[ball1].Pos - _ball[ball2].Pos);
    centerNorm.Normalize();

    // Project the velocity vector on the centerNorm
    Vector projVelocity1 = Dot(centerNorm, _ball[ball1].Vel)*centerNorm;
    Vector projVelocity2 = Dot(centerNorm, _ball[ball2].Vel)*centerNorm;

    // if in same direction
    if (Dot(projVelocity1, projVelocity2) > 0) {
        // if the first one is moving faster than the second, don't interfere
        // first one is identified by dot with centerNorm
        if (Dot(centerNorm, projVelocity1) > 0) {
            if (projVelocity1.Length > projVelocity2.Length)
                return;
        }
        else if (projVelocity1.Length < projVelocity2.Length)
            return;
    }
        // they are not moving in the same direction
    else if (Dot(centerNorm, projVelocity1) > 0)
        return;

    // calculate tangetnt
    Vector tangentVelocity1 = _ball[ball1].Vel - projVelocity1;
    Vector tangentVelocity2 = _ball[ball2].Vel - projVelocity2;

    // New vel is sum own tangent and projection of the other
    Vector newVelocity1 = tangentVelocity1 + projVelocity2;
    Vector newVelocity2 = tangentVelocity2 + projVelocity1;

    // collision with static ball is like colliding with a wall
    if (_ball[ball1].GetType() == typeof (StaticBall)) newVelocity2 = tangentVelocity2 - _ball[ball2].Vel;
    else if (_ball[ball2].GetType() == typeof (StaticBall)) newVelocity1 = tangentVelocity1 - _ball[ball1].Vel;

    // assign
    _ball[ball1].Vel = newVelocity1;
    _ball[ball2].Vel = newVelocity2;
}
```

EDIT: added solution, found by Tariks answer

Comment: Probably without a second ball moving you are not getting enough movement to make them stop colliding in just one frame. I think you can calculate the penetration amount and undo it before the collision ends. Modern physics engines like PhysX are permissive to a little amount of penetration, PhysX call it "skin width"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a regular ball (non-static) at rest, a ball that would collide with it with a tangent velocity of zero and a normal velocity v would cause the colliding ball to come at rest and the ball that was at rest to move with velocity v in the same direction as the colliding ball. In the case of the "static" ball, the colliding ball stops and the static ball does not move either. They stick. To correct this, the static ball should be handled like a wall or more appropriately a column on which other balls bounce. The tangent velocity should be conserved but the normal velocity v should become -v.

Comment: I think I follow, but not sure on how to program this, I tried some things, but what do you exactly mean with the normal velocity ( what variable is that in my code)

Comment: Ok I think I found it, before the assign I added the folllowing

            if (_ball[ball1].GetType() == typeof(StaticBall)) {
                newVelocity2 = tangentVelocity2 - _ball[ball2].Vel;
            } this make the ball just bounce off the static one